# How to create maven profile & run each profile with different XML suites according to the profile activated?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to maven and to maven profiles. I'm working on an automation maven project and I'm trying to create different profiles. What I want to do is that each profile will run different xmlsuites according to the profile activated.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Jenkins</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <echo>Jenkins profile</echo>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>xml/jenkins.xml</suiteXmlFiles>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>Ticket</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <echo>Ticket profile</echo>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>xml/Tickets.xml</suiteXmlFiles>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Above is what I have done. I hope any could give me a hand in giving me some pointers on how to do it.

Now I'm getting the following error when running the automation on jenkins:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-         plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project ipos: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Automatizacion IPOS\Ticket profile is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the cleanest implementation is to have a single configuration of the plugin to run every build, and simply define a property token that varies from one profile to the next.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Jenkins</id>
        <properties>
            <my.echo>Jenkins profile</my.echo>
            <my.xml.files>xml/jenkins.xml</my.xml.files>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>Ticket</id>
        <properties>
            <my.echo>Ticket profile</my.echo>
            <my.xml.files>xml/Tickets.xml</my.xml.files>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>

<!-- DELETE THIS LINE: IS A TYPO
                    <echo>Ticket profile</echo>
-->

<!-- PROFILE-DRIVEN SUBSTITUTION -->
                        <echo>${my.echo}</echo>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>${my.xml.files}</suiteXmlFiles>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: please copy error message up in original post so that whitespace can be read correctly. thx

Comment: There was an extraneous <echo>Ticket profile</echo> in the pom file. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: it was the echo in the pom file, deleted it and worked like a charm. Thanks on the help!

Comment: 333kenshin, how do you handle for example when a profile has more xmlsuites than the other?.

Comment: Alas maven does not allow passing lists as properties. You would have to go back to you original config. Speaking of which, the use of echo block looks fishy. What if you just get rid of that? Also, the inner suiteXmlFiles should be singular ie suiteXmlFile without the trailing 's'